# Accessing variables with the same name at different scopes

Tags: c++, scope

With

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

        int a = 1;

int main()
{
        int a = 2;

        if(true)
        {
                int a = 3;
                cout << a 
                     << " " << ::a // Can I access a = 2 here?
                     << " " << ::a << endl;
        }
        cout << a << " " << ::a << endl;
}
```

having the output

```
3 1 1
2 1
```

Is there a way to access the 'a' equal to 2 inside  the if statement where there is the 'a' equal to 3, with the output

```
3 2 1
2 1
```

**Note**: I know this *should* not be done (and the code should not get to the point where I need to ask). This question is more "*can* it be done".

Comment: I don't know if there is syntax for this (I doubt it), but note that in practice, since both variables are in the same function, you will *always* control both of them, so you are free to simply rename one of them...

Comment: Easy. Rename the variables a1 a2 a3 rebuild it will now work. Seriously even if it was allowed it would be in the bad practice section of every coding standard. Use unique names for each of your variables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you can't, a (2) is hidden.

Ref: 3.3.7/1

> A name can be hidden by an explicit
>   declaration of that same name in a
>   nested declarative region or derived
>   class (10.2).

Ref: 3.4.3/1

> The name of a class or namespace
>   member can be referred to after the ::
>   scope resolution operator (5.1)
>   applied to a nested-name-specifier
>   that nominates its class or namespace.
>   During the lookup for a name preceding
>   the :: scope resolution operator,
>   object, function, and enumerator names
>   are ignored. If the name found is not
>   a class-name (clause 9) or
>   namespace-name (7.3.1), the program is
>   ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.  You are basically overriding the inherited scope of a locally, and it will use that local copy over any inherited ones.

Basically like a child object overriding a function or variable of the parent object, it will use it's copy of it regardless of what the parent had.

Comment: Its not like the class level scoping - in that case there is a syntax to explicitly refer to the other scope.

Comment: Yes, but I was simply referring to the default behavior.