# How to access a local area variable at the other local area?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm recently studying C++ language.

I have been wondered how to access local variable "a" of local area[1] at local area[2] watching the follow code.

How to do that?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

///// global area /////
int a = 1;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ///// local area[1] /////
    int a = 2; //<= how to access this "a" at local area[2]?

    cout << "global area [a] : " << ::a << endl;
    cout << "local area[1] [a] : " << a << endl;
    {
        ///// local area[2] /////
        int a = 3;
        cout << "global area [a] : " << ::a << endl;
        cout << "local area[2] [a] : " << a << endl;
        cout << "local area[1] [a] : " << ?????? << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: Why do you want this? I'am not sure, but may be trying access via inderect addressing through %ebp (x86) can help you.

Comment: You simply can't. If you in an inner scope declares a variable that shadows the declaration of an outer scope, the variable of the outer scope is unavailable. The only exception is variables in the global scope, thanks to the `::` operator.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187891/accessing-variables-with-different-scope-in-c

Comment: It's just curiosity. I have been know that simple answer is "can't." :o

Comment: Joachim's answer seems reasonable. Thanks everyone. :D

Comment: "how to access local variable "a" of local area[1] at local area[2]" As long as you access the variable `a` *before* the second `a` is declared (i.e. move `cout << "global area [a] : " << a << endl;` to before `int a = 3;`, it will work. Probably now what you wanted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. When you declare a variable in the inner scope, it shadows the outer scope's variable and the language doesn't provide any way to access it like it does for global variables.

Even if it did support this however, it would still be bad practice to name your variables the same. Imagine having to handle a large number of scopes and the complexity that would be required!

Simply use different variable names for intermediate variables, it makes both writing and maintaining the code easier.

Comment: Thanks Veritas for detail explanation. :D

Answer (score 1):

You need a bit of help from the outer scope:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ///// local area[1] /////
    int a = 2; //<= how to access this "a" at local area[2]?
    int& alternative_name = a;

    cout << "global area [a] : " << ::a << endl;
    cout << "local area[1] [a] : " << a << endl;
    {
        ///// local area[2] /////
        int a = 3;
        cout << "global area [a] : " << ::a << endl;
        cout << "local area[2] [a] : " << a << endl;
        cout << "local area[1] [a] : " << alternative_name << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```